# how to do something while you are waiting a Thread.join()

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to do something while my Thread is waiting for a join() method
all i want to do is  only change the name of the button while waiting but it's not working... and i don't know why
here's my awful code:

```
 if( e.getSource()==botonFiltro ){
            double [] datosFiltro2 = {
                    (Double.parseDouble(montoTextField.getText())),//0monto
                    (Double.parseDouble(txtPorcentaje.getText())/100),//1porcentaje
                    (Double.parseDouble(txtPrecio.getText())),//2precio
                    (Double.parseDouble(txtRango.getText())/100),//3rango
                    (Double.parseDouble(txtPMasDuro.getText())/100)//4pMasDuro
                    };
            double [] datosFiltro1= {};
            botonFiltro.setText("Filtrando");
            HiloLanzarFiltro hilo = new HiloLanzarFiltro(programa, datosFiltro1, datosFiltro2);
            Thread tFiltrando = new Thread(hilo);
            tFiltrando.start();
            try {
//              while(tFiltrando.isAlive()){
//                  botonFiltro.setText("Filtrando.");
//                  Thread.sleep(500);
//                  botonFiltro.setText("Filtrando..");
//                  Thread.sleep(500);
//                  botonFiltro.setText("Filtrando...");
//                  Thread.sleep(500);
//              }
                tFiltrando.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
//              
            }
            this.programa= hilo.getPrograma();
            String[] l = new String[programa.getCompañias().size()];
            int i= 0;
            for(Compañia c: programa.getCompañias()){
                l[i++]=c.getSymbol();
            }
            JListaPrincipal.setListData(l);
            lblCompaiasEncontradas.setText("Compa\u00F1ias encontradas: "+programa.getCompañias().size());
            botonFiltro.setText("Filtrar");

        }
```

The commented lines are the "thing" that i wanted to do...
Thanks.

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/simple.html

Comment: You should be able to use `join(long millis)`.

Comment: 'Do something while you are waiting ' is a contradiction in terms. `Thread.join()` is a blocking operation. You're blocked. You can't do anything.

Comment: What do you mean, "It is not working?"  What do you expect it to do?  What does it actually do instead?

Comment: Also, why do you set the button title three times in the loop?  It's a loop.  Setting it once should be enough.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, James...  but other comments were much more helpful than yours... but thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

Move changing label to your "tFiltrando" thread. *
You can either wait or execute tasks, never both.

*To be honest, there is also one thing you need to understand: UI manipulation should be done from the UI thread.

So I suggest reading about [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) . It should help you much.

Comment: SwingWorker sounds great, i was trying to make something with it but i can't make the "botonFiltrado" makes an "animation" like ". .. .. " you know? like it's doing something important... it still waits for the SwingWorker....

Comment: Have you used a publish() method to send state changes to UI thread? Have you overridden a process() method to make use of that changes and do something with your UI components?

Comment: I think there is the problem, the UI is the main thread, plus my program has its own Collection to do stuff, maybe i have to change all code... :( what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

There is a very basic and simple way to archive this.
Simply change the name of the button right before

```
tFiltrando.join();
```

And you can change the name of the button using the last line in the run() method.
This works for me i hope this will help you.

Comment: @YagoRodriguez Did you try rearranging the frame or repainting the applet,which is suitable for your application.
Most of the time you need to revalidate the fraes in order to change the ui in java SE.